# Using ssh through an expect script on cygwin

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, cygwin, expect

I'm trying to execute commands remotely over ssh using an expect script that will log in with a password. So far I have the following script (details changed of course):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh user1@cpu3.lab.ie
expect "password:"
send "psw123\r"
expect "$"
send "mkdir pswdtest\r"
```

I name this script `testpswd.sh` and then run`chmod +x testpswd.sh`, `d2u testpswd.sh` and `./testpswd.sh`.

Apparently the script manages to login because I get the `Last login:...` prompt. However, after this the script seems to wait for a bit and then exit back out of ssh, without making a directory called pswdtest (as I can check afterwards).

I have tried looking up tutorials etc and changing the script above in all ways I could think of, e.g. `expect "user1@cpu3:~$"`instead of `expect "$"` and so on.

I'm running windows and use cygwin (hence the `d2u`), and the network I'm logging into uses Linux.

Any ideas?

Comment: While developing an expect script, always add `exp_internal 1` at the top of the script: expect will show you what it's matching (or not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While developing an expect script, always add `exp_internal 1` at the top of the script: expect will show you what it's matching (or not).

Perhaps you could match the prompt with this: `expect -re {\$\s*$}`

After you `send` something, you should `expect` something

```
exp_internal 1
set prompt {\$\s*$}
spawn ssh user1@cpu3.lab.ie
expect "password:"
send "psw123\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "mkdir pswdtest\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Running the script created a long string of stuff i don't understand in the terminal.. If you feel inclined to have a look I put it up at http://pastie.org/9489548

Comment: Looks like it works. Remove the `exp_internal` line now.

Comment: Indeed it does! I stupidly thought it didn't because of all the text, and didn't check. Thanks!